# How/When/Where to Extend Gem Classes (via class_eval and Modules) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, initialization, module, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the recommended way to extend class behavior, via `class_eval` and modules (not by inheritance) if I want to extend a class buried in a Gem from a Rails 3 app?

An example is this:

I want to add the ability to create permalinks for tags and categories (through the ActsAsTaggableOn and ActsAsCategory gems).

They have defined `Tag` and `Category` models.

I want to basically do this:

```
Category.class_eval do
  has_friendly_id :title
end

Tag.class_eval do
  has_friendly_id :title
end
```

Even if there are other ways of adding this functionality that might be specific to the gem, what is the recommended way to add behavior to classes in a Rails 3 application like this?

I have a few other gems I've created that I want to do this to, such as a `Configuration` model and an `Asset` model.  I would like to be able to add create an `app/models/configuration.rb` model class to my app, and it would act as if I just did `class_eval`.

Anyways, how is this supposed to work?  I can't find anything that covers this from any of the current Rails 3 blogs/docs/gists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do this as follows, first add a file to config/initializers where you can require the files that contain your extensions:

```
# config/initializers/extensions.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/category.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/tag.rb"
```

Then you can just re-open the classes and add whatever else you need:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category
  has_friendly_id :title
end
```

Only downside is that the server has to be restarted for any changes to these files to take effect, not sure if there is a better way that would overcome that.

Comment: i have the same issue, i get `LoadError: Expected app/models/tag.rb to define Tag`

Comment: MhdSyrwan : It means that inside your 'tag.rb' file, the first class to be define should be called exactly "Tag", so it seems you just didn't name it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rails_engine_decorator** gem:
https://github.com/atd/rails_engine_decorators

Just add in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_engine_decorator'
```

And user `class_eval` in your decorators:

```
/app/decorators/models/category_decorator.rb
/app/decorators/models/tag_decorator.rb
```

It works for me. I hope you find it useful!